# The name of app not appear in my list on Archive - organizer of xcode to validate or Distribution

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to send a new version of my app for apple store, but in my organizer when I click in Validate or Distribute, after inform my login I can't see the name of my app on the list, on the select list below I can see my provisioning profile normally, but the name of the app not appear on the select list above.

Thank You In Advance.

Comment: Try to Rearchive,  Product->Archive

Comment: Did you set up your update on iTunes Connect?

Comment: Hello this was it.

It is first time that i try to upload of a second version of app and I still not create the second version in itunes connect.

I created now and the name of app appear normally in my xcode for Validation and Distribution.

Thank you very much for your time Guys.